# Meaurable mapping from probability space to Banach space $C([0,1])$

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, and $\{X_t:0\leq t\leq 1\}$ be a continuous stochastic process. We can then map $\Omega$ into Banach space $C([0,1])$ in a natural way, by sending $\omega$ to the continuous function $X(\omega)$.

My question is: how to show that this mapping is measurable when $C([0,1])$ is equipped with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

The hint says that $\|x\|\leq 1$ if and only if $|x(t)|\leq 1$ for all $t$ in a countable dense subset of $[0,1]$. But I have no idea how this hint is related to measurabilty of the mapping $\omega\mapsto X.(\omega)$.

Comment: Closed balls are a generator of the Borel algebra, so it’s sufficient to check that the preimage of closed balls is a measurable set. In particular you want to check that the closed unit Ball is measurable (then you can obtain all the others by translations and dilations). That’s where you have to use the hint now.

Answer (score 0):

Let $D\subseteq[0,1]$ be dense and countable.

Then according to the hint: $$\{|X|\leq 1\}=\bigcap_{t\in D}\{|X_t|\leq1\}$$showing that - if the $X_t$ are measurable - the set $\{|X|\leq1\}$ is measurable.

Of course more generally it can be proved that $\{|X-f|\leq r\}$ is measurable for all $r\geq0$ and $f\in C[0,1]$.

Proved is then that $X^{-1}(\mathcal V)\subseteq\mathcal F$ where $\mathcal V$ denotes the collection of closed balls in $C[0,1]$.

In general we have $X^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal V))=\sigma(X^{-1}(\mathcal V))$ so that: $$X^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal V))=\sigma(X^{-1}(\mathcal V))\subseteq\mathcal F$$

And here $\sigma(\mathcal V)$ can be recognized as the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $C[0,1]$, so we are ready.